# AttributeError: 'SelectIOLoop' object has no attribute 'asyncio_loop'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, tornado

My Jupyter notebook is not connecting to the kernel

I tried downgrading the tornado but still I am facing the same issue.

I am facing this error in my Jupyter terminal

```
AttributeError: 'SelectIOLoop' object has no attribute 'asyncio_loop'
[W 19:25:12.866 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 83c825dc-ba85-4fa8-bc62-f423dff6f718
```

Comment: Which Python version and Tornado version are you running?

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need to upgrade your version of Tornado to at least 5.0. The asyncio-based event loop became the default in that version, and it appears that the version of jupyter you are using is relying on this. (jupyter should update their dependency requirements so that the package manager can know this automatically. I'd also recommend they not access the `asyncio_loop` attribute directly because it's not a part of the IOLoop public interface and is not guaranteed to remain present).